# how to open the save file dialog box in python without using tkinter

Tags: python, savefiledialog

I am trying to create vi editor kind of  app  using python, that takes input from command line
and, provides option to save the typed text .So I need to use the save dialog box without using tkinter. How can I write python script that makes the call to windows save file dialog api

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pywin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32ui__CreateFileDialog_meth.html)

```py
import win32ui

dlg = win32ui.CreateFileDialog(0)
dlg.SetOFNInitialDir(r'C:\Users\jezequiel\Desktop')
dlg.DoModal()

print(dlg.GetPathName())
```

Comment: How can achieve the same thing without using some third-party modules

Comment: You can always just ask your users to pass in the file path as a command-line argument you can get from `sys.argv[1]` or you could just prompt them to type in the path using `input(...)`.